# Interactive Scatter plots based on user input

Tags: python, r, user-input, scatter-plot, interactive

I need to create a specific scatterplot using 3 data columns, x,y,z, (height, weight, ID number) as the basic inputs.

I have height, weight, and a unique identifier for each of ~2000 individuals in the set. I want the user to be able to highlight “their location” within the scatterplot of all the data point precisely. To do that out of 2000 datapoints, they’ll need to input their unique ID into a text box, executing, and altering the  graph:
a)”accent” the unique input data point (e.g., change the individuals specific point to red while other data points remain gray)

b) as a sort of “tool tip”:  Provide the exact values of height, weights and IDnumber in a readable “box” somewhere in or near the graph area, preferably in some open area of the graph’s “state space” This is mainly to let them note their recorded values in our dataset. (Yes, they presumably know their own height and weight… but imagine they’d like to check on whether we have misenterwd their values in the dataset)

I figure there’s an interactive graph package that allows this filter-by typed-input-value-z option, but have only seen filter options that are a small number predefined categories. For example what I have seen permits a drop down box to filter data based on Z. The problem is that my drop down for ID would have as many values as data points and that’s 1000s… so unwieldy compared to my text box idea.

I would like to do this in R or a package that can easily (Im a Stats user mainly, so my do not have much programming skills are limited to writing basic batch programs, .do files, with canned procedures). A non R package that will easily let me create, edit and slap this in a webpage would certainly do.

Comment: The R Plotly package can do all of your request with ease https://plotly.com/r/

Comment: In base R `plot`, `points` and `identify` can do this on X11, windows and quartz devices except the info will either be placed on the screen near the point or shown on the console depending on your `identify` call.  `rownames(BOD) <- letters[1:6];
plot(BOD, pch = 20, cex = 1.5);
highlight <- function(id) points(BOD[id, ], col = "red", cex = 2);
highlight("c");
otherinfo <- seq(10, 60, 10);
identify(BOD, labels = paste(rownames(BOD), otherinfo), cex = 0.5)`

Comment: I’ll check it out.